# UPDATE statement only works with FETCH FIRST

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am trying to update a table of serials with their associated order's create date. Orders can have duplicate numbers eventually, so this connection is needed. The key on the table is the serial number.

I am updating the new field `MYCRTDAT` using the following SQL. It appears to work correctly, but only with the `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` statement. 
I verified that the rows updated with the correct date by quickly looking through them.

When *NOT* using that statement, it returns with an error that **a subselect of a basic predicate has produced more than one row**

I think this error makes sense, but I don't understand how VC2.SERIALNUM is 'passed' --- is it as a singular value or all the rows at once? And if it's all the rows at once how does `FETCH FIRST` not just return the first row every time?

```
UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE VC2
SET MYCRTDAT = (
-- Get Date from Associated Table
SELECT
    MO1.CRDT
FROM 
SCHEMA.TABLE VC1
  LEFT JOIN  SCHEMA.M1 MO1 ON
    VC1.ORDER = MO1.ORDER
    AND VC1.ITEM = MO1.ITEM
WHERE VC2.SERIALNUM = VC1.SERIALNUM
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
);
```

IBM DB2 for i - 7.1 (POWER SERIES)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have what's known as a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).  The `VC2.SERIALNUM = VC1.SERIALNUM` is why it's correlated.

Conceptually, for every value `VC2.serialnum`  the subquery is run with that value.

Thus, why `FETCH FIRST` is needed and why it returns the first row for each serailnum.

You can imagine, a correlated subquery often performs very poorly.  In some cases, the Db can re-write the query so that it doesn't have to repeatedly access the inner table; particular in the case of an `UPDATE` of a single column like you have.

You might want to look at the `MERGE` statement, you should have it at 7.1.

Comment: If conceptually, the subquery is run with just that value, I would say `FETCH FIRST` shouldn't be needed?  (Given my table has no duplicates, which it does not) (Also the `correlated subquery` terminology was foreign to me, so thanks!)

Comment: @CodyG. If it doesn't have duplicates, then yes...but you wouldn't see the error message in that case.  I suspect that while `TABLE` may not have duplicates for serialnum...your join is fanning out and returning multiple rows for a given serial num,

Comment: Bingo bango: `your join is fanning out` *smacks self*

Answer (score 0):

I think better version of this query should be by using MERGE statement

```
MERGE INTO SCHEMA.TABLE VC2
USING SCHEMA.TABLE VC1 LEFT JOIN  SCHEMA.M1 MO1
...
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE MYCRTDAT = MO1.CRDT
else
ignore
```

Comment: Sorry didn;t notice @Charles mentioned the merge statement already in his answer